# How to add a sub collection to a freshly created document in firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an importer for some documents in firebase.

I need to have a sub collection(not just an array) for a specific property of each document I add.

Currently I've the following code, which doesn't seems to work:

```js
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync("files/" + file);
let spot = JSON.parse(rawdata);
var spotFirebase = {
    id: spot.Id,
    sourceId: spot.SourceId,
    type: spot.Type,
    location: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(spot.Latitude, spot.Longitude),
    description: spot.Description,
    address: spot.Address,
    city: spot.City,
    country: spot.Country,
    price: spot.Price,
    parkingCost: spot.ParkingCost,
    opening: spot.Opening,
    name: spot.Name,
    features: spot.Features,
    activities: spot.Activities,
    rating: {
        ratingCount: spot.Rating.RatingCount,
        ratingAverage: spot.Rating.RatingAverage
    }
}

db.collection("spots").add(spotFirebase).then(function (docRef) {
    console.log("Document ", file, " written with ID: ", docRef.id, ", index: ", index, ". ", spot.Rating.UserRatings.length);

    spot.Rating.UserRatings.forEach(ur =>
        docRef.collection("userRatings").add(
            {
                date: ur.Date,
                username: ur.UserName,
                review: ur.Review,
                note: ur.Note,
                reviewSource: ur.ReviewSource
            }).then(function (subDocRef) {
                console.log("Review ID  ", subDocRef.id, " written");
            }).catch(function (errorReview) {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", errorReview);
            }));
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

1. I've no Error displayed
2. I've never the message "Review ID ... written"
3. Obviously, I end with the spot document written, but without any user rating.

I guess I'm not adding correctly the sub collection properly.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The code wasn't waiting for the additions to the sub collection to complete before terminating.

This edit factors the addition into the subcollection into a testable function, collects the promises to create each new doc in a `promises` array, then waits for all of those (`Promise.all()`) to complete before terminating...

```
function addUserRating(parentRef, ur) {
  const newDoc = {
    date: ur.Date,
    username: ur.UserName,
    review: ur.Review,
    note: ur.Note,
    reviewSource: ur.ReviewSource
  }
  return parentRef.collection("userRatings").add(newDoc).then(result => {
    console.log("Review ID  ", result.path, " written");
    return result
  })
}

db.collection("spots").add(spotFirebase).then(function (docRef) {
  console.log("Document ", file, " written with ID: ", docRef.id, ", index: ", index, ". ", spot.Rating.UserRatings.length);
  let promises = spot.Rating.UserRatings.map(ur => addUserRating(docRef, ur))
  return Promise.all(promises)
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error("Error adding document(s): ", error)
})
```

Comment: I've tested your solution, but still no error and still no user ratings added.

Comment: What do you see in the log?

Comment: So that makes one suspect that `spot.Rating.UserRatings` is an empty array.  I see that that's undefined in my code (and in your question).  Did you skip a line that says `let spot = docRef.data()`? We won't see the loop run unless the spot document contains an object called Ratings and that object contains a non-empty array called UserRatings.

Comment: I was thinking of this too, it's why I added `spot.Rating.UserRatings.length` in the log, and I've all items with 10 to 20 ratings.

Maybe to give a bit more context: `spot` is an original JSON file, then I build `spotFirebase` based on `spot`. I need to have different naming, some property of another type(like `GeoPoint`), and this rating collection. I added how this is populated.

Comment: And here you can get one example file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uFrLPKgSa-fQ2deYVW7JGZbHxU-HnJ6E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you have >0 items in the UserRatings array, then we can be certain that addUserRating is called.  How about logging the object you're trying to save in there before you try to save it?